# Increase LVM storage after expanded RAID5 by 4TB?

Tags: lvm, partition, proxmox

So I've been running 3x 4TB (ST4000VN008-2DR166) in RAID5 for quite a while and wanted expand it, by adding a fourth HDD. The migration was successful and the RAID Controller (LSI MegaRAID SAS 9261-8i) is showing the full 10.913TB as available storage:

```
user@server:~ # storcli64 /c0 show
..
TOPOLOGY :
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT      Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 -   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  Y  10.913 TB dflt N  N   dflt N      N
0 0   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  Y  10.913 TB dflt N  N   dflt N      N
0 0   0   252:0    27  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N
0 0   1   252:1    26  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N
0 0   2   252:2    25  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N
0 0   3   252:3    24  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

VD LIST :
----------------------------------------------------------------------
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache Cac sCC      Size Name
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0/0   RAID5 Optl  RW     No      NRWBD -   ON  10.913 TB seagate-raid
----------------------------------------------------------------------

PD LIST :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                 Sp Type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0    27 Onln   0 3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000VN008-2DR166    U  -
252:1    26 Onln   0 3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000VN008-2DR166    U  -
252:2    25 Onln   0 3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000VN008-2DR166    U  -
252:3    24 Onln   0 3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000VN008-2DR166    U  -
252:4    28 UGood  - 1.817 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD2003FYYS-02W0B1 D  -
252:5    29 UGood  - 1.817 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD2003FYYS-02W0B1 D  -
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

user@server:~ # storcli64 /c0/v0 show migrate
VD Operation Status :
-----------------------------------------------------------
VD Operation Progress% Status          Estimated Time Left
-----------------------------------------------------------
0 Migrate   -         Not in progress -
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

`fdisk -l` is showing `/dev/sda` with 10.9 TiB in total, but `seagate--raid-vm--101--disk--0` is still on 7.3 TiB:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 10.9 TiB, 11999999164416 bytes, 23437498368 sectors
..
Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 15624998878 15624996831  7.3T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/seagate--raid-vm--101--disk--0: 7.3 TiB, 7999913459712 bytes, 15624830976 sectors
..
Device                                           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mapper/seagate--raid-vm--101--disk--0-part1  2048 15624830942 15624828895  7.3T Linux filesystem
```

Datacenter > Server > Disks > LVM:
[image]
[image]

I tried extending `seagate-raid` by using `qm resize 101 scsi1 +3636G`, but Proxmox itself isn't recognizing the size change. So how to safely expand the virtual disk without loosing the data?

```
user@server:~ # lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/seagate-raid/vm-101-disk-0
  LV Name                vm-101-disk-0
  VG Name                seagate-raid
  LV UUID                DKJ4bA-396x-QyWq-79qE-JZ7A-cIZh-uLKXow
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ariola, 2019-02-25 23:02:39 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                7.28 TiB
  Current LE             1907347
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

user@server:~ # pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda1
  VG Name               seagate-raid
  PV Size               7.28 TiB / not usable 4.98 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1907347
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          1907347
  PV UUID               2UG4tr-Ug3O-HKKA-P5tp-yyYx-9Sio-k43bOM

user@server:~ # pvs
  PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda1  seagate-raid lvm2 a--    7.28t     0
  /dev/sdb3  pve          lvm2 a--  111.54g 13.88g
user@server:~ # vgs
  VG           #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  pve            1   5   0 wz--n- 111.54g 13.88g
  seagate-raid   1   1   0 wz--n-   7.28t     0
user@server:~ # lvs
  LV            VG           Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  data          pve          twi-aotz-- 59.91g             91.39  3.92
  root          pve          -wi-ao---- 27.75g
  swap          pve          -wi-ao----  8.00g
  vm-100-disk-1 pve          Vwi-a-tz-- 20.00g data        91.74
  vm-101-disk-1 pve          Vwi-aotz-- 40.00g data        91.01
  vm-101-disk-0 seagate-raid -wi-ao----  7.28t
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user@server:~ # pvs
  PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda1  seagate-raid lvm2 a--    7.28t
```

Extend this partition, with tools like `parted resizepart`. Should be able to set the end to 100%
 in `parted`.

Extend the PV with `pvresize /dev/sda1`

Extend LVs with `lvextend --resizefs`

---

Linux LVM doesn't need partitions on PVs. Next time you create new PVs or new VGs, consider giving it the entire disk , like  `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Proxmox uses LVM to manage partitions and virtual disks. I was able to enlarge the disks size in Proxomox and my virtual system. Thanks! I made a post [over here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/increase-lvm-storage-after-expanded-raid5-by-4tb.61623/), where I explain my steps.